# Why redirect not working?

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to log to data base all URL that user type.

After this if the path exists I want to redirect the user to path

Else I want to leave the user in the root directory.

**The URL that I type** `http://www.mydomain.com/folder1/index.php`

**The output screen**

```
folder1/index.php
Array ( [0] => folder1 [1] => index.php ) url = to folder 1
folder1/index.php
```

**The root directory index.php**

```
<?php
        if ($_GET['url']!= "") {
            // url not empty there is query string
            $url = $_GET['url'];
            $url = rtrim($url, '/');

            echo ($url.'<br />');
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            $file = $url[0];
            print_r($url);
        }

        else // url empty it is root directory
            {echo ('<br /> url empty <br />');}

        if ($url[0] == 'folder1'){
            echo ('url = to folder 1<br />');
            $path = $url[0].'/index.php';

            //the path exists do redirect to folder1/index.php
            echo $path ;
                 header( 'Location: http://www.mydomain.com/{$path}' ) ;
        }
?>
```

**The Htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) //www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule \.(sql)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(txt)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(zip)$ - [F]
RewriteRule \.(rar)$ - [F]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#  Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   Options -Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Many thanks

Comment: You should remove `echo $path ;`

Comment: You cannot output anything before the call to `header()`, it must appear before any calls to `echo`

Comment: On top of other comments, you are trying to echo a variable within single quotes. That won't work as you expect.

Comment: ok I delete all the output , it is still not working

Answer (score 2):

I think its the quote problem change with double quotes

```
             header( "Location: http://www.mydomain.com/{$path}" ) ;
```

Comment: it is still not working you can see it http://www.kidslearning4fun.com/folder1/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `echo` before this line and write `exit();` after that

```
header( "Location: http://www.mydomain.com/{$path}" );
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have any output before any header line, so you have to remove all echoes before the header location sentence:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['url']!= "") {
        // url not empty there is query string
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');

        $url = explode('/', $url);
        $file = $url[0];
    }

    else // url empty it is root directory
        {}

    if ($url[0] == 'folder1'){
        $path = $url[0].'/index.php';

        //the path exists do redirect to folder1/index.php
        header( "Location: http://www.mydomain.com/$path" ) ;
    }
```

And as you are using a variable inside the string, you shall use double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: But if you do so, you will be redirecting to an element also catched by the .htaccess and you will trigger the script again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this, (i.e) php variable should come out of quotes and get concatenated,

```
header( "Location: http://www.mydomain.com/".$path) ;
```

**Remove the echo before redirecting - MUST**

Comment: You don't have to concatenate the variable. If it is in the string it will work fine so long as it has double quotes. If it is an array index or property it would be encased in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Any html out put should not be there before the

header( 'Location: http://www.mydomain.com/{$path}' ) ;

Following 2 lines will be helped you to avoid htlm before the header statement.

Put ob_start(); in begin of your code.

Put ob_end_flush() end of your code.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good explanation on why you should not do this: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?639005-when-to-use-ob_start%28%29-and-ob_end_flush%28%29&s=7a5010e105740d969d48d8f3c1615f17&p=4386140&viewfull=1#post4386140